# Install sympy for python34 in windows 8

Tags: python, sympy

I download **sympy-0.7.6**. Now it is in `download directory`. I install **python** in `C drive` `(c:\Python34).`
Now how to install the `sympy`. There is no `.exe` file in `sympy` directory. But have a **setup.py**.

```
My OS is windows 8.
```

How I install or use **sympy for python 3.4 in windows 8 64 bit system**.???

I downloaded the `sympy` for perform some `integration and other mathematical operations.`

Please help...

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I successfully installed sympy in window 7 machine from source code.

```
download the zip from https://github.com/sympy/sympy
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/sympy/sympy.git 
cd sympy 
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to run `python setup.py install` in the sympy's folder that you have download (in your download directory). Installation instructions are at https://github.com/sympy/sympy#installation

This will work with python3 as well.
But I think that you are facing problem in running python commands. You must be able to run python to install and use Sympy.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to install [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads), which comes with SymPy (as well as tons of other useful Python libraries and the IPython notebook).  The latest version of Anaconda comes with an older version, so you'll want to open a command prompt after you install it and run

```
conda update sympy
```

to get the latest version.

Comment: I highly recommend Anaconda as I tried doing it on my own, or using other install packages in order to get 3.4, I could only get Anaconda with everything working, especially the notebook.  I just checked and I have sympy 0.7.6 , is this not the latest?

Comment: It is the latest now (it wasn't at the time of this writing). In general, though, the SymPy release cycle does not sync up with the Anaconda release cycle, so running `conda update sympy` is a good idea.

Comment: @asmeurer How to  we can install SymPy  using the anaconda in cmd on Windows?